# доступ к кнопке back navigationbar в андроид

Tags: android

Как перепрограммировать кнопку "back" navigationbar  для подключения к ней меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так:

```
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Клик
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашей Activity переопределите метод

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //do something
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```